# JOIN with table only if parameter condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, inner-join

I need to do a join with table B only if a parameter @param is not null or if it has a specific value.

I don't want to add IF/ELSE because the store is really big for doing that.

My store return over 50 parameters and makes joins with 10 tables.

I just want to skip one of those joins if a declared @param condition is meet.

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

```
DECLARE @param INT = NULL;

SELECT 
    /* HERE GOES A LOOT OF PARAMETERS */
FROM 
    T0 T
    INNER JOIN  T1 B ON T.attr1 = B.attr1
    LEFT JOIN   T2 TFD ON T.attr2 = TFD.attr2
    LEFT JOIN   T3 TTT ON (TTT.attr3 = TFD.attr3)
    INNER JOIN  T4 U ON B.attr4 = U.attr5 AND U.attr6 = @attr6
    -- The following commented section is the one that i want to skip if @param is NULL
    /*LEFT JOIN @tvp P ON  (
                            (P.attr11= TFD.attr9 AND T.attr8 = P.attr8 AND P.attr7 = 1) OR 
                            (P.attr11 = TFD.attr9 AND T.attr8 = P.attr8 AND P.attr7 = 0 AND B.attr4 = @attr5) OR 
                            (TFD.attr9 IS NULL AND P.attr8 = T.attr8)
                                    )*/
    LEFT JOIN   T4 FTB ON FTB.attr1 = B.attr1
    LEFT JOIN   T6 S ON S.attr10 = T.attr10
    LEFT JOIN   @splittedElementsIds SETI ON SETI.item = T.attr9
    WHERE
        (@attr9 IS NULL OR T.attr9 = SETI.item)
    GROUP BY
        /* LOOTS OF GROUP BY PARAMETERS */
```

Comment: Why don't you just always join and then put the @param as a condition on that join? Make it a left join and you're probably in business. Dynamically changing your query typically is NOT a good idea because it messes with cache plans and things of that nature

Comment: Are you trying to do INNER JOIN with this table? If so you can do in WHERE condition. If you post some sample code, it may help.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Use the @param condition in ON clause, here is an example:

```
select * from A
  left join B on A.id = B.id and @param1 = 'X'
  left join C on A.id = C.id and @param2 = 'Y'
  etc...
```

Comment: `select *` is probably not appropriate.

Comment: Right, the star is only for simplicity of course. Fields should be enumerated in the final select.

Comment: . . That's not it.  As expressed in this answer, the result set will have columns from tables that the OP does not want in the query.  The values will be `NULL`, but the columns will be there.

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions:

1 - You can create your sql statement dynamically by concating strings and run it by sp_executesql

2 - Using `Union all` as below

Assume `t2` is table you wan to join conditionally, and `@param` is what you want to do condition based on

```
;With query as 
(Select * from t1
 inner join t3
 inner join t3)

Select * from query
Where @param = 1

union all 

Select * from query
inner join t2
Where @param = 2
```

Comment: Tip: Don't do option 1 ever

Comment: To be honest, I don't think option 2 makes sense for this scenario either but its hard to say without seeing a query from him

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns.  The `join` in question -- because it is *optional* -- would not seem to be returning any columns in the query.  Hence, I presume it is only being used for filtering.

If so, I might recommend using `exists` instead:

```
select . . .
from . . .
where @param <> 'true' or exists (select 1 from b where b.? = x.?)
```